# Why is my spring security not forwarding the request to authentication-success-handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to implement Spring Security in my application and somehow I am having some problem with it. Whenever I hit one of the intercepted URLs  then I do get a custom login page. However after successful login, my Spring Security does not forward it to authentication success handler.

My `security-context.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/reviewer/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="any" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/home"
            authentication-failure-url="/authfailed?errormessage=authentication.login.failed"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
             />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logoutsuccess" logout-success-url="/logoutsuccess" />
        <!--  <access-denied-handler ref="" error-page="/signup" /-->

    </security:http>
    <bean id="successHandler"
        class="com.reviewthedoctors.security.WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:jdbc-user-service id="userService"  data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select email,password, true from users where email=?"
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select email, authority from users where email =?  " />
</beans>
```

And my `WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler` class is:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCache;
import org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.SavedRequest;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;


public class WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RequestCache requestCache = new HttpSessionRequestCache();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws ServletException, IOException {
        SavedRequest savedRequest = requestCache.getRequest(request, response);
        if (savedRequest == null) {
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            return;
        }
        String targetUrlParameter = getTargetUrlParameter();
        if (isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl()
                || (targetUrlParameter != null && StringUtils.hasText(request.getParameter(targetUrlParameter)))) {
            requestCache.removeRequest(request, response);
            super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
            return;
        }
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
        String targetUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }

    public void setRequestCache(RequestCache requestCache) {
        this.requestCache = requestCache;
    }
}
```

Similarly my login page is:

```
<div class="page_content">
    <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp"
        style="margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 50px; width: 400px;">
        <div class="mdl-card__title">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Login</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" style="width: 400px;">
            <form action="/revewthemovies/j_spring_security_check" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="email"
                        name="j_username" modelAttribute="email" /> <label
                        class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Email</label>
                </div>
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="password"
                        name="j_password" modelAttribute="password" /> <label
                        class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">Password</label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit"
                    class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent"
                    style="width: 150px; margin-bottom: 100px" value="Add" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Similarly my `web.xml` is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>PRASM</display-name>
    <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>/pages/home.jsp</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I have absolutely no idea why the request doesnot reach `WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Whenever I login in I end up at this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/j_spring_security_check
```

Does anyone have any suggestion regarding this?

Comment: from jan 28 2015, you have asked 13 questions but you have not accepted any answers. Didnt the answers solve your problems?

Comment: Hi sorry for any inconvinience caused. I am not that active in Stackoverflow and if that's a problem I will definitely accept answers for all the questions. Sorry again.

Comment: @Smrita you have to `implement  AuthenticationSuccessHandler`..`WebAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements  AuthenticationSuccessHandler`

Comment: You should accept that answer which solved your problem so that it will be useful for future users who faces the same problem. If you had not get any answers then you can set bounty to attract more answers

Comment: Okay @SpringLearner I will try to follow your suggestions:)

Comment: I wonder why the question has been downvoted? I had a pretty distressing time as my application's console didnot give me any pointers at all which in my mind is a perfect time to ramble in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was that that I forgot to declare the following in my web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```